# Create QString in a printf manner without std and std::strings

Tags: c++, qt5

I was given a XML which defines format of cells in a table, such as:

```
%.2f
%d.%m.%Y %R
```

Now I wanna use that format on some number (or date) to produce formated number line this:

```
Before           After
12.54893    =>   12.54
```

I tried this for numbers. `formating` is QString containing format like `%.2f`. Value is `QVariant` guaranteed to be numeric.

```
formating.toString().arg(value.toLongLong());
```

But the result rather sucks:

[image: image description]

So I guess I need a different `QString` method. This is my **old, outdated** `std::` based approach which **must be removed**:

```
QByteArray FSA = formater.toString().toLatin1();
const char*  fs = FSA.data();
// See locale pseudo-singleton below
boost::format f( fs, STDLocaleSingleton::Instance() );
return QString::fromLatin1( boost::str( f % value->getLongValue() ).c_str() );

// Probably saves some memory, I think
class STDLocaleSingleton {
    STDLocaleSingleton(){};
public:
    static const std::locale &Instance(){
        static std::locale loc("");
        return loc;
    }
};
```

Comment: how about: `QString::asprintf("%.2f", value.toDouble())`?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#sprintf - it's probably not available in Qt5, but in Qt4 should work

Comment: @m.s. Ah sorry, should've mentioned - I'm using Qt 5 and I I've read about `QString::asprintf`.

Comment: All this method chaining and singleton stuff; looks like java.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the [QString::number()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) method.

What you will need to do though is extract the formatting information from your format, but a Regular Expression should work good enough for this.

```
QString format("%.2f");
int precision;
double before = 12.54893;

QRegularExpression regexp("\\%\\.(\\d+)f");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regexp.match(format);
if(match.hasMatch() == true) {
    precision = match.captured(1).toInt();
    qDebug() << "Precision: " << precision;
    QString after = QString::number(before, 'f', precision);
    qDebug() << "Before: " << before;
    qDebug().noquote() << "After : " << after;
} else {
    qDebug() << "No match";
}
```

I see the output is rounded a bit, but if that is a problem you will have to do something else:

```
Precision:  2
Before:  12.5489
After :  12.55
```